# How can I change the Text color of the thumb(ON/OFF) for Android Switch widget?

Tags: android, android-widget

I tried setting the textAppearanceAttribute. But it doesn't work.
 There is another attribute textColor but that is for the label of the switch.

```
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/double_margin"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textAppearance="@style/SwitchTextAppearance"
        android:track="@drawable/transit_switch_track"
        android:thumb="@drawable/transit_switch_thumb" />

<style name="SwitchTextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/red</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I have the same issue... thx for the feedback

Comment: @bvanvelsen Hey yes I solved this. Check my answer. Let me know if this approach would work for you.

Comment: here have some upvotes for you feedback :) appreciate it... However what I was looking for was be able to change the textcolor of the textOn and textOff text. I'm still unable to make that work... thanks anyway...

Comment: hey @pgiitu have you resolve different colors for android:textOff and android:textOn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using a drawable instead of trying to fiddle around with colors.

So here is the code:

```
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/double_margin"
        android:switchMinWidth="50dp"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""
        android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb"
        android:track="@drawable/switch_track"
        android:checked="false" />
```

switch_track.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_off" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_on" android:state_checked="true"/>

</selector>
```

switch_thumb.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle"/>

</selector>
```

This is how my Switch looks now:

[image]

Switch_off image

[image: switch_off image]

Switch_on image

[image]

toggle is just a white image for thumb.